# Unity UI Buttons not working (not clickable)

Tags: unity, unity-ui

Buttons Easy, Medium and Hard can not be clicked even though Restart Button was clickable from the start. All of the buttons have interactable checkbox on and raycast target on. Shadow panels and Bacground - Game Menu also have raycast target on.
[image: hierarchy and game view difficulty buttons]

[image: hierarchy and game view restart button]

Comment: Can you show us the inspector setup for these buttons, or walk us through the steps to reproduce this problem, starting from an empty scene?

Answer (score 1):

To confirm which button the system thinks is available do this:

- [image]Run the game.
- Find your EventSystem in the hierarchy and expand it.
- Move your mouse/pointer over each button and look for pointerEnter
  changing.

Do this on the button that works and the ones that don't. What do you see?

Comment: Thank you for your help! In the EventSystem pointerEnter instead of Easy Button it's Hearts Panel! Do you think that changing the Sorting and Order Layer in CanvasRenderer will help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the Hearts Panel, I resized it, added Graphic Raycaster to Background, Buttons and Shadows and it started working!

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail, I know this is a bit of a specific problem, but if anyone has the same issue. Perhaps some extra clarification would be useful.